# Convert VB DependencyProperty to C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

I cannot figure out how to convert VB code of DependencyProperty  to C# code.

I have read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140620/WPF-Tutorial-Dependency-Property) article... but anyway I need some help.

```
Public Shared VideoDirectoryProperty As DependencyProperty = _
DependencyProperty.Register("VideoDirectory", GetType(String), GetType(Webcam), _
                                        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf DirectoryChange)))

Private Shared Sub DirectoryChange(ByVal source As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

and C# code I have got:

```
public DependencyProperty VideoDirectoryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("VideoDirectory", typeof(string), typeof(WCam), 
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(DirectoryChange)));

private void DirectoryChange(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
{

}
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Checklist for Defining a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to define `VideoDirectoryProperty` as static as your VB code says it is `Shared`.

Also you have `GetType(WebCam)` in VB but `typeof(WCam)` in C#.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty VideoDirectoryProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "VideoDirectory",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(WebCam), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(DirectoryChange)));

private static void DirectoryChange(
    DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```